# Fetching list of subobjects of a certain type anywhere in the object

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

If i have the following structure:

```
    [BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
    [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Class0), typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2))]
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class Class0 : BaseClass {}

    public class Class1 : BaseClass
    {
        public Prop prop = new Prop1();
    }

    public class Class2 : BaseClass
    {
        public Prop prop1 = new Prop1();
        public Prop prop2 = new Prop2();
    }

    //

    [BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
    [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Prop1), typeof(Prop2))]
    public abstract class Prop {}

    public class Prop1 : Prop {}

    public class Prop2 : Prop {}
```

And I insert one of each `Class` object into a mongo database:

[image]

Is it possible to build a query capable of returning a `List<Prop>` (by searching for the _t values and projecting the subdocuments) in an object-oriented way?

Something along the lines of:

```
        IMongoCollection<BaseClass> data = db.GetCollection<BaseClass>("data");
        List<Prop> props = data.AsQueryable().OfType<Prop>();
```

And if it is not possible in an object-oriented way, is it achieveable by any type of mongo query?

Comment: IMongoCollection<BaseClass> data = db.GetCollection<BaseClass>("data");
                FilterDefinition<BaseClass> props = Builders<BaseClass>.Filter.Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(Prop));
                var FinalData = data.Find<BaseClass>(props);   may be this hel, I am not sure

Comment: That can never work since you are checking if the type of a BaseClass object (a) is of type Prop.